# Photoshop: Two different shapes, one on top of another, remove excess parts?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

Sorry if the title is confusing. Basically, I have two shapes like this (black glasses, white shape in the middle) on separate layers:

[image]

I want to remove the excess parts marked in red like this:

[image]

How can I do this in Photoshop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now realise you're working with Shapes. You can do this as follows:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + `Left Click` the layer thumbnail of the top layer to select it.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + `Left Click` the layer thumbnail of the bottom layer to select intersections:

[image]

Click on the top layer again and click `Add Layer Mask`

[image]

[image]

Hopefully this should give the result you wanted.